# Finding a word using Buffered Reader

Tags: java, while-loop, bufferedreader, readline, stringtokenizer

I'm parsing through a file which has the following text and same format,

name:_____   gender:_____

age:_____    grade:______

When parsing, I want to first look to see if "gender: f" or "gender: m" & if for example "gender: f" then I will create a new girl object and set her name, age and grade. Else if it was a boy, I'd create a new boy object and set his name, age and grade.

My code works for only one gender right now. I'm not sure how to implement it to search for the other gender.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.trim();
    st = new StringTokenizer(line);
    if (line.endsWith("gender: f")) {
        f = new female();
        st.nextToken(); 
        String name = st.nextToken();
        f.setName(name);                    
    } else if (line.startsWith("age:")) {
        st.nextToken();
        String age= st.nextToken();
        f.setAge(age);
        line = br.readLine();
    }       
}
```

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: I think you might be overthinking things, because you already have the general idea up there.  just add another `else if`to the block.  `else if (line.endsWith("gender: m")) { ... }`  BTW, since you're doing stuff like key/value things, you should look into JSON

Answer (score 0):

You cant try this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class FileReaderExample
{
        private Person person;

        private Person readFile()
        {
          File file = new File("d:\\text.txt");
          try
          {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
              line = line.trim();
              StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
              if ( line.endsWith("gender: f") )
              {
                person = new Female();
                st.nextToken();
                String name = st.nextToken();
                person.setName(name);
              }
              else if ( line.endsWith("gender: m") )
              {
                person = new Male();
                st.nextToken();
                String name = st.nextToken();
                person.setName(name);
              }
              else if ( line.startsWith("age:") )
              {
                st.nextToken();
                String age = st.nextToken();
                person.setAge(age);
                line = br.readLine();
              }
            }

          }
          catch (IOException io)
          {
            // 
          }

          return person;
        }

      public abstract class Person
      {
        private String name;
        private String age;
        private String grade;

        public String getAge()
        {
          return age;
        }

        public void setAge(String age)
        {
          this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
          return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
          this.name = name;
        }

        public String getGrade()
        {
          return grade;
        }

        public void setGrade(String grade)
        {
          this.grade = grade;
        }

      }

      public class Female extends Person
      {
         public Female() {}
      }


      public class Male extends Person
      {
         public Male() {}
      }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file only contains a single person, here is what you can do :

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.trim();
    st = new StringTokenizer(line);

    if (line.endsWith("gender: f")) {
        person = new Female(); // Your Java classes's name should start with a capital letter (coding convention)
        st.nextToken(); 
        String name = st.nextToken();
        person.setName(name);                    
    } else if (line.endsWith("gender: m")) {
        person = new Male();
        st.nextToken(); 
        String name = st.nextToken();
        person.setName(name);                    
    } else if (line.startsWith("age:")) {
        if(person != null) { // person can be null if the first line of your file is wrong
            st.nextToken();
            String age = st.nextToken();
            person.setAge(age);
        }
        line = br.readLine();
    }       
}
```